# xCode - IBOutlet элементы nil

Tags: ios, swift, view, imageview

Добавляю элементы на ViewController, но при запуске, они все nil, причем не важно на какой ViewController и какой элемент. В чем может быть проблема?

Пример:

На ViewController (изображение ниже) есть два элемента. Тот, что справа (updateImageView), я добавлял неделю назад, а тот, что слева (inviteFriendImageView) сегодня.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при запуске приложения, элемент, который я добавил сегодня(человечек с плюсиком)  оказывает nil!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Outlets проверял миллиард раз все норм
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И так происходит на любом ViewControllere при добавлении любого элемента, подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Может обращение к ним не там где надо?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ошибку. Оказывается, что у меня был второй storyboard(Russian), который был создан, когда я подключал русскую локализацию и не заметил этого. А программа запускалась как раз с русского, где не было нужных элементов на View.